# bootstrap 4.1 mobile menu button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

I have a bootstrap 4.1 based HTML webpage in which I used the following script to reuse the HTML code in other pages;
The demo page can be seen here
http://skillsteer.com/clients/didx/

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#header').load('header.html');
   $('#footer').load('footer.html');
});
```

Before using this script the bootstrap-based mobile menu was opening perfectly but after using it, the menu stopped to work and not opening at all.

Kindly help me fix this issue.
Thanks,
Farhan

Comment: You should load that script before the bootstrap JS. Right now you are loading bootstrap.min.js before the menu is available to the DOM, therefore the bootstrap menu function could not find the appropriate element to set up event listeners for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because header.html has not been loaded before you wire up your mobile menu click handler.  Pick one of two options below:

1. Move the click handler script into header.html
2. Change header load to this:

```js
$('#header').load('header.html', function() {
  $('.resposive_menu_bar').click(function(){
   $('.menu').children('ul').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```